Stabilizer of Color code
I have a question about stabilizers in color codes. In color codes, neighboring faces share two qubits, and the weight of the stabilizers is even.

My questions are:
1.Can the product of stabilizers always be represented by an even number of X operators or Z operators?
2.Conversely, if an even number of X or Z operators act without changing the syndrome, can we say that the operator applied is a stabilizer?

First, keep in mind that the color codes you show are specific examples of so called triangular color codes, so properties you infer from them might not apply to other color codes such as the color code on a torus. This one encodes 4 logical qubits and has also only stabilizers with even weight but has an even distance.

Yes, if you start with a basis of stabilizers with even weight that always share an even number of qubits, by taking the product of two stabilizers, the product will have a support which is the sum modulo 2 of the supports of the initial stabilizers. Since the intersection of the two initial supports is even, the support of the product stabilizer will also be even.

This is true for any Pauli operators not just stabilizers and will apply to any stabilizer code.

The operators that when applied do not induce any syndrome are either stabilizers or logical operators. This question then becomes does there exist logical operators with even weight?

The answer to this depend on the color code as well as how you count your operators.
Does the logical operator $X_1X_2X_3Z_1Z_2Z_3$ (qubits 1,2 and 3 are the bottom qubits of your first picture) involves 3 or 6 operators? If you count $X$ and $Z$ separately, then you have an operator involving an even number of $X$ or $Z$ operators that is not a stabilizer.
If only the overall support counts (or if you only consider operators that are either all $X$ or all $Z$), then the answer is probably that any even weight operator is a stabilizer for triangular color codes. Indeed, since there is only one logical qubit, then any logical operator is the product of a logical operator with minimal (odd) weight with some stabilizers. Since multiplication by stabilizers does not change the parity (see 1.) of the support, any logical operator must have an odd weight.
Note that 2. is obviously false in a color code with even distance such as the one I mentionned earlier. This is because any logical operator with minimal (even) weight will be a counterexample.

Thank you for answering my questions so thoroughly; your insights are very helpful.
As you pointed out, I’m considering the triangular color code.
Regarding your response to (1), is it possible to say that the product of an arbitrary number of stabilizers (three or more) can also be represented by an even number of operators? When dealing with three or more stabilizers, the situation becomes more complex, especially when they share a qubit, like the central qubit in diagram (a).

Regarding your response to (2), it was very helpful to learn that this can be rephrased as the question of whether there are an even number of logical operators.
In (2), I had been considering only the overall support and hadn’t thought about counting Z and X separately.
t seems there are none in the case of a color code defined on a plane. Acknowledging (1) makes it clear why there are only odd-weight logical operators.
I understood, thank you.

@Kmai The colored stabilizers are just a particular basis of all the possible stabilizers: the product of an arbitrary number of stabilizers is always a stabilizer. So when one says "the stabilizers are of even weight", I expect it to mean all stabilizers, not only the colored one.

It is probably not very difficult to show that any stabilizer is even weight if there exist a basis of even weight. The induction would be on the number $k$ of colored stabilizers used in the decomposition of any product of colored stabilizers.

OK
Sorry for the late reply.
